# How to a set linear gradiente color to the SwiftUI toolbar background?

Tags: swift, swiftui, toolbar

I am getting in trouble trying to set a linear gradient color directly to the .toolbarBackground function.

The background of the toolbar is what I don't want. My desire point is the background of the button.

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct InitialPageView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button {
                    print("")
                } label: {
                    Text("OI")
                }
                .padding(30)
                .background(LinearGradient(
                    colors: [Color("IPU_secondary"), Color("IPU_principal")],
                    startPoint: .topLeading,
                    endPoint: .bottomTrailing))

            }
            .toolbarBackground(LinearGradient(
                colors: [Color("IPU_secondary"), Color("IPU_principal")],
                startPoint: .topLeading,
                endPoint: .bottomTrailing),
                               for: .navigationBar)
            .toolbarBackground(.visible,
                               for: .navigationBar)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "location.circle")
                        Text("Localização aqui")
                    }
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75262480/use-gradient-for-toolbarbackground-swiftui

Comment: Similarly to the answer given above, but with need to resort to UIKit, you can add the gradient as an image to Assets, and then create the background color as `Color(uiColor: UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "gradientImage")))`. I would probably make it a `static let` somewhere convenient to avoid recreating it all the time.